# How to: PHP Ajax page update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a input field and 2 buttons to add/remove words from a database.
I'm using 3 php files. The main file which is outputting the html code, the addtag.php, which can add a word and the removetag.php file which can remove a word.

I want to call addtag.php when the plus is clicked and send the content of the input field. removetag.php should be called when clicking on the minus symbol.

addtag.php and removetag.php should run in the background and the page should only update `<tagboxtxt>`.

The elements below are listed multiple times on the same page. There are different links and values but the elements are the same.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<bdiv>
<div>
<a href="001.mp4"><img src="001.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<tagbox>
<form>
<input type="text" id="tag" name="tag">
<input type="hidden" id="hash" name="hash" value="23547">
<button class="button" type="submit" formaction="addtag.php" method="GET">+</button>
<button class="button" type="submit" formaction="removetag.php">-</button>
</form>
<tagboxtxt>foo bar</tagboxtxt>
</tagbox>
</bdiv>

<bdiv>
<div>
<a href="002.mp4"><img src="002.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<tagbox>
<form>
<input type="text" id="tag" name="tag">
<input type="hidden" id="hash" name="hash" value="67889">
<button class="button" type="submit" formaction="addtag.php" method="GET">+</button>
<button class="button" type="submit" formaction="removetag.php">-</button>
</form>
<tagboxtxt>bla huh</tagboxtxt>
</tagbox>
</bdiv>
```

I know that Ajax is the way to go, but I cant get it working.

I've tried to use function below. How should I use that in my example?

```
function addtag () {
      $.ajax({
        url:"addtag.php",
        type: "POST",
        success:function(result){
         alert(result);
       }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you already tried in order to send an AJAX request?

Comment: @StuntHacks I've added what I've used. I did some testing with that but I guess I'm missing some skills.

Comment: What isn't working? What is written in the alert?

Comment: You forgot to mention that you were using jQuery. You've described how you want ti to work, but provided no information at all about how the code you have implemented behaves. As it stands, this question is not answerable.

Comment: @symcbean I dont know if JQuery is the best solution. In first place I need to send the value of the input field to the php file which takes the value into a variable and runs in the background.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the javascript that captures the click on the 'plus' button, and calls your ajax function. Try pasting this  javascriptsnippet below your function:

```
//Execute on page ready
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.plusSign', function() {
        addTag();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i would call a js file and have it reference the two add and remove php files--i have mocked this up for you  first in the main file that outputs the html put this

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tag.js"></script>
</head>

<tagbox>
    <input type="text" name="tag">
    <div class="cssCircle plusSign" id="plus">&#43; </div>
    <div class="cssCircle minusSign" id="minus" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:25px;">&#8211;</div>

</tagbox>
```

This will allow you to call the js file to run ajax. the js file named tag.js should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#plus").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addtag.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({word: $("#tag").val(),}),
            success:function(result){
                alert(result);
                                    }
        });

});

$("#minus").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "removetag.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({word: $("#tag").val(),}),
            success:function(result){
                alert(result);
                                    }
        });

});
});
```

this should accomplish what you need

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question. This should explain better what I'm looking for.